# how to get a value sent as a parameter in phpmailer addAddress function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending one single email to multiple users , let's assuming that there is a link into email that has been sent, I'd like to know who clicked the link and visited the page, my situation is not the same is that scenario is but my question is how to get a parameter sent in  addAddress function of phpmailer , example :

```
$this->mail->addAddress('user1@gmail.com', 'u1');
$this->mail->addAddress('user2@gmail.com', 'u2');
$this->mail->addAddress('user3@gmail.com', 'u3');
```

Can I recuperate these values , u1, u2, u3..  use it for example here :

```
mylink.com/param1/u1/
```

Comment: you would need to add tracking to the link in the email

Answer (score 0):

the only way to know who clicked on a link in an email is to add tracking to that link:

```
http://yoursite.con/emailtrack/XXXX/real_link
```

have the emailtrack  page get the XXXX log it, then redirect to the real page. XXXX could just be the users email address or some other id. Each email would have to be sent separately as the link will have to change.